# Azure Function, Swagger, OpenApi

Tags: c#, azure-functions, swagger, openapi

as in the title I'm playing with: Azure Function, Swagger and OpenApi.

Look at the following code:

```
[Function("v1/job/selectAll/{agentId}")]
[OpenApiOperation(operationId: "selectAllJpbs", tags: new[] { nameof(TctJob) }, Summary = "Select all jobs.", Description = "This select all the jobs of an agent.", Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]
//[OpenApiSecurity("petstore_auth", SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2, Flows = typeof(PetStoreAuth))]
[OpenApiParameter(name: "agentId", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Description = "The id of the agent to download the jobs", Required = true, Type = typeof(Guid))]
//[OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(List<TctJob>), Required = true, Description = "List of all the jobs of the requested agent.")]
//[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(System.Collections.Generic.List<ITctJob>), Summary = "Job list.", Description = "List of all the jobs.")]
[OpenApiResponseWithoutBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Summary = "Invalid ID supplied", Description = "Invalid ID supplied")]
[OpenApiResponseWithoutBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.NotFound, Summary = "", Description = "")]
[OpenApiResponseWithoutBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, Summary = "Validation exception", Description = "Validation exception")]
public async Task<IActionResult> SelectAllJobs(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get")] HttpRequestData req,
    [FromRoute(Name = "agentId")] Guid agentId)
{ ... }
```

If I run this code and try to access to the Swagger home page (`.../api/swagger/ui`) everything works fine.

Now if I remove the comment from the line of `OpenApiRequestBody` or `OpenApiResponseWithBody` I obtain the following error:

Fetch error. Internal Server Error http://localhost:7031/api/swagger.json

Note that the swagger.json file is exactly where it should be...

Some info about the environment:

- Target framework: .Net 6
- Azure Function Version: 4
- AzureExtensions.Swashbuckle: 3.3.2

**UPDATE**

This is my `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
        <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
        <AssemblyVersion>1.0.0</AssemblyVersion>
        <PackageVersion>1.0.0</PackageVersion>
        <Authors>The Cloud Team</Authors>
        <Company>The Cloud Team</Company>
        <Description>This package contains the Database Updater service.</Description>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.16.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Abstractions" Version="1.2.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.11.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\TCT.Backend.Services.Common\TCT.Backend.Services.Common\TCT.Backend.Services.Common\TCT.Backend.Services.Common.csproj" />
      <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\TCT.Common\TCT.Common\TCT.Common.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="host.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
        <None Update="local.settings.json">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
            <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

What's wrong? Any suggestion or workaround?

Regards,
Attilio

Comment: Please share your `.csproj` file.

Comment: Check the below solution and try it once.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an Azure Function `.NET 6 Isolated`.

Thanks @[Justin Yoo](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/apps-on-azure-blog/general-availability-of-azure-functions-openapi-extension/ba-p/2931231) for the code.

I have tried to run the Function by using `OpenApiRequestBody` and `OpenApiResponseWithBody`
Iam able to run the Code without any error.

My `.csproj` file.

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.14.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Http" Version="3.0.13" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi" Version="1.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.10.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

***My Sample `Function1.cs`:***

```cs
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Attributes;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.OpenApi.Core.Enums;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;

  [Function("v1/job/selectAll/{agentId}")]
  [OpenApiOperation(operationId: "selectAllJpbs", tags: new[] { "TctJob" }, Summary = "Select all jobs.", Description = "This select all the jobs of an agent.", Visibility = OpenApiVisibilityType.Important)]
  //[OpenApiSecurity("petstore_auth", SecuritySchemeType.OAuth2, Flows = typeof(PetStoreAuth))]
  [OpenApiParameter(name: "agentId", In = ParameterLocation.Query, Description = "The id of the agent to download the jobs", Required = true, Type = typeof(Guid))]
  [OpenApiRequestBody(contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Required = true, Description = "List of all the jobs of the requested agent.")]
  [OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Summary = "Job list.", Description = "List of all the jobs.")]
  [OpenApiResponseWithoutBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, Summary = "Invalid ID supplied", Description = "Invalid ID supplied")]
  [OpenApiResponseWithoutBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.NotFound, Summary = "", Description = "")]
  [OpenApiResponseWithoutBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, Summary = "Validation exception", Description = "Validation exception")]


  public HttpResponseData GetAll([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
  {
      _logger.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

      var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
      response.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

      response.WriteString("Welcome to Azure Functions!");

      return response;
  }
```

***My `Program.cs` file:***

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.OpenApi.Extensions;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults(worker => worker.UseNewtonsoftJson())
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

***Output:***

[image]

***Swagger.json***
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After further checks, I noticed the fact that the line

```
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(List<ITctJob>), Summary = "Job list.", Description = "List of all the jobs of the agent.")]
```

has `contentType: "application/json"` and `bodyType: typeof(List<ITctJob>)`. So I decided to change the bodyType from `typeof(List<ITctJob>)` to `typeof(List<ITctJob>)` and it works!

So the right code is:

```
[OpenApiResponseWithBody(statusCode: HttpStatusCode.OK, contentType: "application/json", bodyType: typeof(string), Summary = "Job list.", Description = "List of all the jobs of the agent.")]
```

Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: The response body is set to be a JSON format and the bodyType initially you have set as List, which is a mismatch.

Comment: JSON object contains a set of key-value pairs (returns as a single string), so the body-type has to be a string.